# Database Table Partition in oracle DB 11g

Tags: oracle11g, partitioning

I have a table of size 20GB.I need to perform partition in that existing table,please give your valuable tips and suggestions.

Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Please describe your question. Partition is totally depends up on size of table and parameters in it.

Answer (score 0):

We can create PARTITION in oracle DB by particular column.

```
CREATE TABLE Employee 
   (    
    EMP_ID NUMBER, 
    JOINING_YEAR NUMBER
   )

PARTITION BY LIST (JOINING_YEAR) (
  PARTITION EMP_2017 VALUES (2017),
  PARTITION EMP_2018 VALUES (2018),
  PARTITION EMP_2019 VALUES (2019),
  PARTITION EMP_2020 VALUES (2020),
  PARTITION EMP_2021 VALUES (2021),
  PARTITION EMP_2022 VALUES (2022),
  PARTITION EMP_2023 VALUES (2023),
  PARTITION EMP_2024 VALUES (2024),
  PARTITION EMP_2025 VALUES (2025),
  PARTITION EMP_2026 VALUES (2026),
  PARTITION EMP_2027 VALUES (2027),
  PARTITION EMP_2028 VALUES (2028),
  PARTITION EMP_2029 VALUES (DEFAULT)
)
```